# Understanding why you can discard left-most carry in two's complement arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I have been studying binary numbers.  I cannot understand why you can sometimes discard the left-most carry when adding two negative numbers.  I mean, I can do some samples and see that it works, like $1101 + 1100 = -3 + -4 = 11001 = 1001 = -7$, but I don't really understand what is going on to allow this to work.  Could you explain it?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Two's Complement works](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920772/why-twos-complement-works)

Comment: I agree with the duplicate vote, I think what you really need is just an explanation of why two's complement works. It's not clear to me how to explain specifically the left-most-carry thing other than to just explain how the whole system works, unless you can be a bit more specific about why the carrying confuses you.